# C++ is it possible to delay initialization of constant static member?

Tags: c++, qt, static-initialization

I am using Qt but this is a generic C++ question. My case is simple, I have a class `Constants` which has a constant static member which I want it to be initialized after certain function calls are made.

Constants.h

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

class Constants
{
public:

    static const char* const FILE_NAME;
};

#endif // CONSTANTS_H
```

Constants.cpp

```
#include "constants.h"
#include <QApplication>

const char* const Constants::FILE_NAME = QApplication::applicationFilePath().toStdString().c_str();
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "constants.h"
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug()<< "name: "<<Constants::FILE_NAME;
    //for those who are unfamiliar with Qt, qDebug just prints out
    return a.exec();
}
```

When compiling I got:

> QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first

So problem here is obvious. When QApplication's static function is called in Constants.cpp QApplication is not installed by Qt yet. I need to somehow wait until `QApplication a(argc, argv);` line is passed in main.cpp

is it possible and if not what else could you suggest to overcome this?

thanks

Comment: Not declaring it as a constant? It's definitely not a constant since it relies on some state at application startup.

Comment: but I need it to be read only once it is assigned?

Comment: I could be wrong, but `QApplication::applicationFilePath().toStdString()` looks like a temporary to me, in which case you're storing a pointer to invalid data.

Comment: For example: use an object (like a String class instance), assign it NULL and check if it's NULL (which means it's not assigned yet).

Comment: You can use `.toAscii()` instead of `.toStdString().c_str()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to return it from a function, keeping it in a static variable. This will be initialised when the function is first called.

```
char const * const file_name()
{
    // Store the string, NOT the pointer to a temporary string's contents
    static std::string const file_name =
        QApplication::applicationFilePath().toStdString();
    return file_name.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Although 2 answers result the same and work well, your answer seems more secure. thanks

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Bad idea to return a pointer to an _automatic_ local. This one is static, so will still exist when the function returns.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right. That never occurred to me.

Answer (score 11):

Typical solution:

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

class Constants
{
public:

    static const char* const getFILE_NAME();
};

#endif // CONSTANTS_H
```

And in cpp

```
#include "constants.h"
#include <QApplication>

const char* const Constants::getFILE_NAME()
{
    static const char* const s_FILE_NAME = QApplication::applicationFilePath().toStdString().c_str();

    return s_FILE_NAME;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you storing a pointer to the contents of a temporary string? Or does `toStdString()` return a reference to something persistent?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: move that comment to OP?

Comment: Good answer, though I'd prefer a namespace over a class with only static members.

Comment: I think I agree. Still, the above might be _typical_ :)